# Как записать в свойство объекта значение из input?

Tags: javascript, html

Только начал изучать JS и вот не выходит записать значение в объект из input(a). Подскажите, пожалуйста. Что для этого нужно?

```
<div class="form-group diametr-choice">
    <label for="diametr">Выберите диаметр цепи:</label>
    <select id="diametr" class="form-control">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Далее Js

```
let selectDiametr;

let model = new Object();
    model.diametr = selectDiametr;
    model.length = 0;
    model.type = "";
    model.price = 0;

document.querySelector('select#diametr').addEventListener("change", function() {

    selectDiametr = (this).value;

});


console.log(model);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При изменении вы записываете в переменную selectDiametr, которая никаким образом не влияет на ваш объект(запись в него происходит еще до изменения пользователем поля, и больше не меняется). 
Перепишите ваш код так:

```
let model = new Object();
    model.diametr;
    model.length = 0;
    model.type = "";
    model.price = 0;

document.querySelector('select#diametr').addEventListener("change", function() {
    model.diametr = (this).value;
    console.log(model);
});
```

А вообще объекты рекомендуется создавать таким образом:

```
let model = {
    diametr,
    lenght: 0,
    type: "",
    price: 0
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и поправления :)